# Show that $x^n-x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Assume it is reducible, then $g(x)h(x)=x^n-x-1$ Note $g(0),h(0),g(1),h(1)=\pm1$ Then I am stuck.

Comment: @Sil This doesn't appear to be exactly the same question.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, it is. It is a standard fact that a monic polynomial with integer coefficient is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}$ if and only if it is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Very well, I am not so knowledgeable about algebra. I will vote to close this question then.